# taxonomy tokens throwing invalid token error

Tags: taxonomy-terms, tokens

I have a drupal 7 site, any time I use a token with taxonomy term in it, I am getting the error,

The Default path pattern for Product (applies to all Product content types with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [term:name].

for example [term:name] or [term:description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!token!token.module/function/token_element_validate/7. Implement hook_form_alter() of form you are trying to submit and look for #element_validate array key, in field you get an error should be

```
  '#element_validate' => array('token_element_validate'),
```

Then you should check  #token_types key value. It can have any value, as examples:

```
 '#token_types' => array('node'),
```

OR

```
 '#token_types' => array('all'),
```

In my case I got similar error in metatag_context module when I was trying to save taxonomy token into metatags context field. Problem was in '#token_types', they was empty, I added array('all') value and form works fine.